# What is the most widely implemented service discovery protocol?

Tags: service, discovery

I am looking for a service discovery protocol (maybe Bonjour or SSDP?) that is widely supported and has implementations available for most of these languages C#, C++, Java, Python.  If it doesn't have the implementations at least it should be relatively easy to implement the protocol yourself. Any suggestions?